Understanding the Role and Connection of veth and tap Interfaces in Firecracker VM with CNI
I'm working with Firecracker VMs and using CNI for network configuration. My current setup involves the following configuration:
/etc/cni/conf.d/fcnet.conflist
{
  "name": "fcnet",
  "cniVersion": "1.0.0",
  "plugins": [
    {
      "type": "ptp",
      "ipMasq": true,
      "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "subnet": "10.0.0.0/18",
        "resolvConf": "/etc/resolv.conf"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "tc-redirect-tap"
    }
  ]
}

On the Host:
When I run ip a on the host, I see the following for the veth interface:
74: veth8d52e569@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 0e:0c:9c:36:83:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns e5d1188b-598a-409d-a125-844d0558f21e
    inet 10.0.0.1/32 scope global veth8d52e569
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b408:58ff:fe66:e16d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

In the Namespace:
Inside the namespace, tap0 and veth0 are shown as follows:
sudo ip netns exec e5d1188b-598a-409d-a125-844d0558f21e ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: veth0@if74: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:c1:a5:c8:f9:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
3: tap0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 6e:92:e2:26:e8:e2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Inside the VM:
Within the VM, the network interfaces are:
ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 6a:c1:a5:c8:f9:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.29/18 brd 10.0.63.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::68c1:a5ff:fec8:f96c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

When firecracker starts i see that tap it's like
INFO[0000] Attaching NIC tap0 (hwaddr 6a:c1:a5:c8:f9:6c) at index 1

corresponds to interface eth0 in vm
similarly when i use tcpdump i see traffic from vm going first through tap then veth0
sudo ip netns exec e5d1188b-598a-409d-a125-844d0558f21e tcpdump -i tap0 -nn -s 0 -v
sudo ip netns exec e5d1188b-598a-409d-a125-844d0558f21e tcpdump -i veth0 -nn -s 0 -v

I understand that tap interfaces are used for network emulation in virtual machines and that Firecracker supports tap interfaces. However, I am having trouble understanding how veth and tap interfaces are connected and their roles in this setup.

How are tap0 and veth0 related in this setup?
I can't find any bridges or rules for iptables

What is the role of tap0 in this context, and how is it linked to the VM's eth0?

Is it possible to see somewhere the connection of tap0-veth, as well as the connection of tap on the host and eth0 inside the vm?


I would appreciate any insights into how these interfaces are connected and their roles in network configuration for Firecracker VMs.
Thank you!
